# Pseudocode Translation to python with ":"

Tags: python, pseudocode

For the following pseudocode:

```
L1 = [(i, L[i]) : i < len(L)]
```

I'm struggling to interpret what it is doing and how to translate it to python, I've tried the following two ideas but i is referenced before assignment.  Mostly I'm struggling to interpret the pseudocode although it should be clear.

```
if i < len(L):
        L1 = (i, L[I])

L1 = (i, L[i]) where(i < len(L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translate it to a list comprehension:

```
L1 = [(i, L[i]) for i in range(len(L))]
```

But Python has a built-in function that does this: `enumerate()`:

```
L1 = list(enumerate(L))
```